# Load image in Picture Box when User Control shows to user

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I want to show a lot of images in a form using User Control, but it's very slow and takes a lot of system memory.

How can I load image in Picture Box when User Control shows to user?

I wrote this sample code. It works fine for 700 images, but I am still looking for best solution.

```
Bitmap myBitmap;
Image myThumbnail;

foreach (var item in queryMatchingFiles)
{
    Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
    myBitmap = new Bitmap(item);
    myThumbnail = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(120, 183, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox {
        Image = myThumbnail,
        Width = 120,
        Height = 183,
        BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
    });

    count++;
    myBitmap = null;
    myThumbnail = null;
}

public bool ThumbnailCallback()
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `it's very slow and takes a lot of system memory` There's a good chance that your original images have a far higher resolution than you are displaying. If so, resize them accordingly either in memory or on disk.

Comment: Use thumbnails to render the set of images and only load a full image when one is selected.